# SubString function in vb.net throwing Exception

Tags: vb.net, string

`FromIp` contains `"192.168.1.1"`. I want to get the last number, but I can't figure out what's wrong here:

```
    Dim str As String
    str = FromIP.Text.Substring(FromIP.Text.LastIndexOf("."), FromIP.Text.Length).ToString()
    MessageBox.Show(FromIP.Text.Length)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested code:

```
    Dim FromIp As String = "192.168.1.1"
    Dim str As String
    str = FromIp.Substring(FromIp.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToString()
    MessageBox.Show(str)
```

- You must add 1 to LastIndexOf to skip the dot
- There no need put the lenght of the Substring when you want all the rest of the string

But this refactored code will work better:

```
    Dim FromIp As String = "192.168.1.1"
    Dim IpPart As String() = FromIp.Split(".")
    MessageBox.Show(IpPart(3))
```

Comment: Alternatively it would be: Dim IpPart As String() = FromIp.Split(".")

Comment: Just to be picky .. you could go

Dim IpPart As String = FromIp.Split(".")(3)

Answer (score 5):

Eduardo has given the correct way of getting the substring - my answer here will just explain why the existing one fails.

[`String.Substring(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) takes a starting position and a *count*. You're basically saying, "Go from position 9 for 10 characters". The documentation explicitly states it will throw:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException [if]
>
> startIndex plus length indicates a
>   position not within this instance.
>
> -or-
>
> startIndex or length is less than
>   zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
FromIP.Text.LastIndexOf(".") + 1
```

instead of

```
FromIP.Text.LastIndexOf(".")
```

and

```
FromIP.TextLength-FromIP.Text.LastIndexOf(".")
```

is the last parameter instead of

```
FromIP.TextLength
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, Substring takes Start,Stop as parameters.

So that would be: `txt.Substring(IndexOf, txt.Length - IndexOf)` or just with one parameter: Substring(IndexOf + 1)